# Pocketbase API Rule to only create record if there isn't already a record with the same values

Tags: pocketbase

Is there a way to create an API rule that only allows the user to create a record if there isn't already one with the same combination of values.
I want it to be possible to have a record with the values "a" and "b" and also one with the values "a" and "c" but not another one with the values "a" and "b".

I tried to do something like

```
NOT IN (SELECT ... FROM table WHERE value_1="a")
```

Answer (score 2):

The most straightforward way seems to be to create a new index on those columns in the edit collection form and check the "Unique" toggle in the new index form.

TL;DR

Click on the collection you want to edit:
[image: Opening the New/Update Index form]

Select "New Index" under unique constraints and indexes. In the New/Update Index Modal, you can toggle "Unique" and select from a list of presets (columns) to add them to the index.
[image: Selecting the name and avatar column for an index]

See this comment from ganigeorgiev on github:
https://github.com/pocketbase/pocketbase/issues/544#issuecomment-1477895278-permalink

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's too late, but now it's possible implement custom hooks inside the instance. So you can create a custom hook to execute before insert on a table and check . Please refer to [this documentation](https://pocketbase.io/docs/js-event-hooks/#onrecordbeforecreaterequest) to know more about it